# Performance concerns when using (Bootstrap) Modals in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

The way I have been dealing with modals in my AngularJS applications is to use ng-include in the index.html to include the modal HTML, and open it using the data-target="#modal" bootstrap attribute.

The problem is that if I have a controller on the modal, then that controller is loaded at startup and never destroyed, since the modal is always in the background. This results in performance issues, for instance if you have a $watch on a large array inside the modal, then it will always run and slow down your digest cycle.

Is there a better way of initializing modals and modal controllers in AngularJS? If not, how would I make sure that a $watch I have inside a modal only runs when the modal is open?

Comment: Building your own modal-controller could be very complex. Have you looked at https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/? It's not an answer to your question but maybe helpful ;)

Comment: What do you mean modal controller? I think you are misunderstanding me. I am not trying to manually recreate bootstrap functionality like opening/closing modals. All I am referring to when I mean the modal controller is the angular controller that controls the view-model on that html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

angular bootstrap (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) does not use bootstrap js itself (uses css only). It is lightweight and modal controllers never instatiate before you open modal. Use link provided, they have very nice documentation with examples.

And anyway if you use ng-if: `<div class="modal" ng-if="shown" ng-controller=... >`
there is no any perfomance penalties

Comment: Can you elaborate on ng-if="shown"? I cannot get it to work.